# In love with a non muslim girl who I want to convert to Islam - is this halal?

Tags: love

I'm actually 14 and the girl I love is 12. She goes to the same school as me and I love her a lot. I don't want to touch and stuff just talk to her and see her. Is it okay If I go up to her and introduce myself, I really want to convert her to muslim by telling more of Islam. And if she really loves me back (because she looked at me with her friends) she will listen to me.

Also we won't convert because she loves me but she loves Allah, and Allah doesn't have a problem with people who convert

Comment: This is not the age of you to be involve in such things, try to focus on education and make your career

Answer (score 1):

She must choose Allah and the Islam way by herself, otherwise she will have converted more because of your pressure on her than true love for Allah.

Talking to her about Islam and showing her how you feel about Allah is enough to let her think about converting. Even if she doesn't convert, you can still love her, and she can still love you.

Answer (score 0):

Loving other humans is a normal and a good act. However if you love her differently than other humans then you might have to carefully evaluate if it's love or just the hormones getting in at the age of 14.

However, if she accepts Islam for Allah, not you, then it will be a great thing.

Answer (score 0):

It is fine to have feelings for one another since it is something out of your control. But, at this young age, it is better to focus more on your studies and your education.
even lowering your gaze upon her, and such acts:

> ˹O Prophet!˺ Tell the believing men to lower their gaze and guard their chastity. That is purer for them. Surely Allah is all-aware of what they do. (24:30)

She needs to choose Allah at her own will. Encouragement is fine unless it does not lead to peer pressure.